# Pathlib - join n parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

I am playing around with Pathlib and trying to find out if there is an easy way to do the following - I have a group of paths from which I want to extract the first 4 parents, and join these 4 into a path.

Alternatively (if possible) I would like to join all parents up to the parent passed a given one, e.g., `c://d1//d2//known//d4//...` here I want to extract up to `//d4`, i.e., the parent just after the 'known' parent.

I know I could just loop over the parts and join up to the nth one, but I am wondering is there a way to do something like the following `p.joinpath(p.parents[0:4])`, `p.joinpath(p.parents[0: 'known_index'+1])`,  or whatever is the most pythonic.

Update:

I managed to join up to the nth with tuple unpacking `print(p.joinpath(*p.parts[0:5]))`, is there a preferred way and I have still not managed to achieve the goal of the alternative case mentioned above.

Update:

I found an option for the 'Alternative' case `print(p.joinpath(*p.parts[0: p.parts.index('PCB_236_237_ARM')+2]))`

I am now just looking for the most pythonic ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pythonic enough to me:

```
p1 = pl.Path('c://d1//d2//known//d4//')
idx = p1.parts.index('known')
p2 = pl.Path(*p1.parts[:idx+1])
```

I use `pl.Path(*segments)` to join the segments because the instance method `p.joinpath()` appends the segments to the instance's `p` own path.